# using imagefit in Django

Tags: django

I'm writing an application in `Django 2.x`

I am trying to use [`django-imagefit`](https://github.com/vinyll/django-imagefit) plugin in my application to resize images on rendering as I have to generate different size of images in template.

According to the instruction in the package documentation, I have added `imagefit` to **INSTALLED_APPS**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...

    'imagefit',

    ....
]
```

and included `url` pattern in `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^imagefit/', include('imagefit.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

now in the template when I try to use `resize` template tag

```
{% load imagefit %}
<img src='{{ course.banner.url|resize:"200x150" }}'>
```

It renders image path as below which is not working

```
/imagefit/resize/200x150//media/course/2018/03/18/image.png
```

whereas without using package, it is rendering

```
/media/course/2018/03/18/image.png
```

which is working perfectly.

I tried to setup `IMAGEFIT_ROOT` like

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_my_project')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn', 'static_root')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn', 'media_root')

IMAGEFIT_ROOT = '/media/'
```

but still it renders same path and image is not working and gives error **file not found**

I think the error could be in `IMAGEFIT_ROOT`, How to properly use `IMAGEFIT_ROOT`?

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I am having a similar problem to yours.

Answer (score 0):

An image is a static file in Django and must be loaded with jinja before it could be rendered.
Eg:

```
{% load staticfiles %} 
<img src='{{ course.banner.url|resize:"200x150" }}'>
```

Comment: `{% loas static %}` is already added and there is no effect of your answer. See question again, it's working without `resize` tag

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should set IMAGEFIT_ROOT one level higher than your MEDIA_ROOT, in your case it's "static_cdn"